# JavaScript Math.random vs. Infinitiy

Tags: javascript

Is there any way that this piece of code can return `Infinity`. We use it in our code to generate a random numbers in the browser but some clients return `Infinity`.

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 5))
```

The only way I can think of is that someone has overwritten `Math.random`

Comment: Which clients? You could check whether `Math.random` has been overwritten by writing it to console. If it isn't native code you know it's been overwritten

Comment: Its mostly in old IEs 5,6,7. But we get the number only as a query parameter of some requests, so there is no way to test this on the clients. Also if someone overwrite it, its not our problem. I only wonder if there is another possible reason for this behavior.